# How can we access the fields of a paragraph in views which is referred by a field of a content type in Drupal 8

Tags: view, drupal-8, paragraph

I have a content type whose one field refers to a paragraph. This paragraph is having title and description. I have given the option of adding as many paragraphs as they want in a content type. I am looking for an option to get all the titles of the created paragraphs in views in Drupal 8

Comment: Can you paste some code to make it easier to understand your issue?

Comment: I have used the paragraph table of contents module for drupal 8. But when I get the toc block, I get the whole content rendered. I want only the title of each paragraph in my toc

Comment: Is there an option to add a relationship b/w content and paragraph in that view? I'd look in that direction.

Comment: I checked that also. But that too is not working out

Answer (score 0):

view_pre_render hook for access the content type field in drupal 8.

```
function MODULENAME/THEMENAME_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == "viewname" && $view->current_display == 'view_machine_name') {
    foreach($view->result as $value){
      $field_value = strip_tags($value->_entity->get('field_name')->value);
      $value->_entity->set('field_name', $field_value);
    }
  }
}
```